# phpspreadsheet can't read Chinese word when read csv file

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I am using PhpSpreadsheet to read files (csv, xls, xlsx).
But when I reading csv files, the content of Chinese word can't read (it's null).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxigu.png)

This csv file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuMX2.png)

This is my code:

```
<?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv;
  $inputFileName = 'input1.csv';
  //load files
  $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
  //change the file to array
  $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
  print_r($sheetData);
?>
```

I had try `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'zh_TW.UTF-8 UTF-8');` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly need to tell PHPSpreadsheet what encoding is used for the csv file using the csv reader's `setInputEncoding()` method

Answer (score 0):

If it is a csv file, you could try the following codes:

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
$reader->setInputEncoding('GBK'); //this line would internally convert chinese gbk to utf-8 encoding
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($excelFile);
$data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```